# Get scroll position to set variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using this to scroll the page. However I would like it to stop scrolling at set positions on the page.

```
var t;
var scrolling = false;

function doScroll() {
    $('body').scrollTop($('body').scrollTop() + 20);
}

$('#pause').on('click',function(){
    scrolling = !scrolling;
    if(!scrolling){ 
        clearInterval(t);
        return;
    }
    t = setInterval(doScroll, 10);
});
```

I was hoping that by adding this to the doScroll function would stop the scroll at positions between 100 and 150 but, it does not.

```
if($("#pause").offset().top >=100 && <150){
         clearInterval(t);
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe a fiddle? Since you are not *moving* `#pause`, the `if` condition looks incorrect. You should be checking `$('body').scrollTop()` instead.

Comment: You have a mistake on your code, it's: if($("#pause").offset().top >=100 && $("#pause").offset().top < 150) { ... }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it! if condition was incorrect, scrolling had to be set to false to allow restart...

```
function doScroll() {
    $('body').scrollTop($('body').scrollTop() + 20);
    if($("#pause").offset().top >=100 && $("#pause").offset().top < 150){
        clearInterval(t);
        scrolling = false;
        return;      
    }
}
```

Thanks to zvona